# How to do column editing in vim?

Tags: vim, editor, vi

Vim is pretty powerful when editing by line - the search/replace tools are modeled to work linewise.

But what if I want to change a particular column across all lines? For example, how can I change the 80th column in my file to a `#` easily?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can use a [substitution](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#:substitute) where the [pattern matches a specific column](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/%5C%25c) (`\%c`):

```
:%s/\%80c/#/<CR>
```

Or you can use [block-wise visual](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/visual.html#CTRL-V) mode:

<kbd>g</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>8</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>|</kbd><kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd><kbd>G</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>#</kbd>

The '[`virtualedit`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'virtualedit')' option can be used to allow positioning the cursor to
positions where there is no actual character:

```
:set virtualedit
```

Comment: visual mode is messy.. is there an easier way to say `replace 80th column with #`?

Comment: @Lazer: Have updated my answer to prefer a `:s` approach (but blockwise visual mode will save you three key-presses!)

Comment: Note that for the block-wise visual mode solution, it would be `79l` to get to the 80th column, not `80l`, because you're starting in column 1. (Or alternatively a better solution, `80|` - 8, 0, pipe)

Comment: @Chris: The [pipe](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#bar) character (which I have used) takes you to the column regardless of your start position. You're right, though, [`79l`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#l) (ell) will work just as well without extra keystrokes.

Comment: @Johnsyweb: whoops, apparently I didn't look quite closely enough... I thought you had used `l` rather than `|` :-/

Comment: Actually, visual block mode only works if you already have text in the desired column. Therfore, the :%s option may be the only one that will work regardless of the existing text. It's really great for "flower-boxing" (what the OP was asking about) or for any situation where you have some ragged-right text and want to force some data into a column that extends past the longest line.

Comment: @JESii: Thanks for pointing that out. I've updated my answer to include `:set ve`, which I think addresses your concern.

Comment: @Downvoter: how would you recommend I improve this answer?

Comment: Your answer, while relevant to the OP's particular example, appears comparatively insane to the one below and is not useful when I arrive from google

Comment: Minor nitpick: The `virtualedit` option isn't a boolean, as the provided example suggests, at least not as of Vim 8.1. It can be set to `block`, `insert`, `all`, or `onemore` (see the linked help for the available options).

Answer (score 165):

To edit a column, follow these steps:

1. Stand on the beginning of the column
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>, then mark across the column you want to edit.
3. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> to insert text at the beginning of the column, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> to append text, **<kbd>r</kbd>** to replace highlighted text, **<kbd>d</kbd>** to delete, **<kbd>c</kbd>** to change... etc.
4. Hit <kbd>ESC</kbd> when done.

I think people (me) sometimes map the column editing keys to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> so it won't collide with visual select line (V) or paste-text if you mapped it as such.

Comment: [Ctrl]+[V] is block-wise visual mode, which @Lazer described as "messy" in response to my answer. This would be my preferred way to do it (using [r] to replace the column with '#'), but the OP has indicated this to be unacceptable.

Comment: @Johnsyweb I thought he meant visual select and then search and replace on the selection using regex, which I find messy (and unnecessary) as well. I don't see why column mode is bad here, but then again I'm not familiar with the OP's code. He could also record a macro and re-run it X times, but that's still more work than column editing.

Comment: I agree with you this is the neatest way to work and perhaps future visitors to this question will find this useful, so you get an up-vote from me.

Comment: ctrl-V and ctrl+A didn't work for me, I (shift-i) and A (shift-a) did, r, d, and c worked as expected.

Comment: I need to hit twice ESC to get things done. And when I press shift+i to insert text, it only shows change in the first line but eventually all selected lines will change.

Comment: Hi @sa125 best answer ever

Answer (score 59):

...I couldn't follow the steps of sa125 (facepalm) so I looked someplace else and found a simpler explanation at: https://blog.pivotal.io/labs/labs/column-edit-mode-in-vi

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> [ and select what ever you want]
2. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> [and write whatever...(check out ** below)]
3. <kbd>Esc</kbd>

*<kbd>c</kbd> without <kbd>Shift</kbd> can be used instead of step 2, to delete selection before insert. And also <kbd>r</kbd> to replace.

**!! Attention Don't be discouraged by the fact that only the first row is changed when you 'write whatever...'!!

Hope it helps!

Comment: It is strange how nothing shows up until after pressing [Esc] and navigating away from the current location.

Comment: I want to add that doesn't work when you remove characters using x. So, in that case the editing in first row doesn't propagate to the others.

Comment: Hi @Alex.S. I think you would need to select with `Ctrl+v` the whole column you want to delete, then press `x`

Comment: I think you should use just `c` instead of `Shift` + `i` to change text

Answer (score 1):

I may be totally off topic here, but if your idea is to avoid long lines, you could have a look at the [colorcolumn](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27colorcolumn%27) option of vim 7.3.

Answer (score 1):

For column-wise editing, [vis.vim](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Applying_substitutes_to_a_visual_block) is really useful. You can block-select your column of interest, and manipulate it with normal commands, and even arbitrary Ex commands. From the example on that page, I have often used the pattern:

```
:'<,'>B s/abc/ABC/g
```

You can Vundle/Pathogen install vis.vim from [github](https://github.com/taku-o/vim-vis):

Plugin 'taku-o/vim-vis'

Answer (score 1):

To remove all `#` in the example below.

1. `ctrl + v` at `#` : (Visual Block) mode
2. drag all `#` s using arrow down or `j`
3. Then press `x` to remove all `#` s

```
# a
# b
# c
# d
# e
# f
```

4. Then press `Esc` to escape from editing

```
 a
 b
 c
 d
 e
 f
```

Comment: Thank you for providing an answer. However, the question was how to add a `#` in column 80, not how to remove it from column 1.